# spl_autoload_register and properties of the $class variable

Tags: php

I have a class with Namespace1, and a class with Namespace2. Sample code looks like:

```
namespace Namespace1

class 1
 {
  //somewhere in here we call new Namespace2\Class2();
 }
```

Here is a really basic autoloader method that I call on startup (It's not production-ready code):

```
public function LoadAutoRegister()
{
  spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $newClass = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    $basePath = realpath(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $file = $basePath.$newClass.".php";

    include $file;
  });
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

 //require autoloader class and call the register method above
 $foo = new Namespace1\Class1();
 $foo-> //Call a method that forces the auto register to search for Class2.php
?>
```

This code works fine until I get to the line that forces the stack to load *Namespace2\Class2.php*. I've inspected the *$class* variable in *spl_autoload_register*, and it's actually passing in *Namespace1\Namespace2\Class2*. Well, that's not good, because the file doesn't live there (and I'm modeling my namespaces off of my directory structure).

Any tips on why the $class is resolving this way and how I can fix it?

Comment: You have simply specified things incorrectly. Since you are already inside `Namespace1`, `Namespace2\Class2` refers to `\Namespace1\Namespace2\Class2`. Write `new \Namespace2\Class2()` to see the difference.

Comment: I believe it's the leading backslash I was missing. Would you mind posting this an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are already inside `Namespace1` at the point where you refer to `Class2` without using its fully qualified class name (FQCN). The reference `Namespace2\Class2` refers to the non-existent class `\Namespace1\Namespace2\Class2`.

You can make either of two easy modifications to solve this:

1. Use the FQCN when instantiating: `new \Namespace2\Class2()` (backslash in front).
2. Import the class with `use Namespace\Class2 as Class2` just after the namespace declaration, which allows you to simply say `new Class2()` to refer to the class.

Note that in the second case you don't have a leading backslash because with `use` you are required to provide the FQCN of the class being imported, so the backslash is implied.